# What is the correct way to use multiple ref values in html?

Tags: html

What should be the correct way to use multiple ref values in HTML?

I have two lines of code in mind. One of which is

`<a href="foo.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener, nofollow">`

and the other one is

`<a href="bar.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">`

Should there be a comma for separate values?

Comment: There is a difference between "rel" and "ref"...

Comment: MDN clearly defines the `rel` attribute as: The attribute must be a space-separated list of the link types values

Comment: @arkascha Yes. I am referring to `rel` and not `ref`, the one that interacts with Google SEO bots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you  have to separate it like this:

```
<a href="bar.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">
```

Comment: I already clearified that more than 10 minutes earlier in the comments ;-)